# How to press Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar in WebdriverIO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

So, the question is how to send keys combination Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar to Chrome under webdriverIO framework?

Have tried

```
browser.keys(['Control', 'Shift', ' '])
```

but hasn't worked well. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `keys` method to send a sequence of keystrokes with the following values `["Control", "Shift", "Space"]`.

You’ll find all supported characters [here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#keyboard-actions)

So, it should be:

```
browser.keys(["Control", "Shift", "Space"]);
```

Comment: Where did you try it?
Actually, it works, just tested it here (https://en.key-test.ru/) with the command I mentioned above.

Comment: I run it on test framework based on webdriverIO. Actually, framework says that command is performed correctly, but system under test doesn't respond it's supposed to respond.
Most key combinations work fine (like Ctrl+S, Ctrl+A, etc.). Seems like I have issue with spacebar itself, but have no idea how to track the problem.

Comment: Yevhen's answer is correct, as application under test doesn't respond properly.